# Книги по разработке архитектуры

Tags: книги

Добрый день, подскажите, а есть ли какие-либо книги по разработке архитектуры программ? Желательно что-то связанное с веб-разработкой, желательно без привязки к какому-либо языку программирования. Просто как продумывать архитектуру, как продумать все возможные решения и выбрать какое-либо, заранее что-либо предвидеть и т.д.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Навскидку:

- [Идеальная архитектура. Ведущие специалисты о красоте программных архитектур](http://www.books.ru/books/idealnaya-arkhitektura-vedushchie-spetsialisty-o-krasote-programmnykh-arkhitektur-fail-pdf-818269/?show=1)
- Мартин Фаулер [Шаблоны корпоративных приложений](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0579-6.html)
- Питер Гудлиф [Ремесло программиста. Практика написания хорошего кода](http://www.books.ru/books/remeslo-programmista-praktika-napisaniya-khoroshego-koda-fail-pdf-646106/?show=1)

Плюс я бы посоветовал посмотреть документацию по веб-фреймфоркам, а также их устройство. Например, 
[YII Framework](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/index).

Плюс в *Исследованиях* есть [тема о создании структуры проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/227851/yii-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (автор - @Shrek). Вполне можно там поспрашивать о конкретных этапах.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться)